# filter users within a given distance in Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-filter

I'm trying to implement a custom filter in Django rest framework, which returns the users within a given distance, I'm using Django filters. I am assuming that latitude and longitude are already provided by front end.

this what I tried. I don't know if it's the right way to do it.
I'm having the following error

```
'RenameAttributes' object is not iterable
```

Here is my code

Views.py

```
def calculateDistance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2):
    lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2 = map(radians, [lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2])
    return 6371 * (
        acos(sin(lat1) * sin(lat2) + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * cos(lon1 - lon2))
    )
class CustomFilter(django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend):
    def filter_queryset(self, request , queryset,view):
        alluser = queryset
        newQueryset = []
        distparam = request.GET.get('distance')
        if distparam and bool(int(distparam)):
            for user in alluser:
                current_user_long = request.user.Longitude
                current_user_lat = request.user.Latitude
                alluser_long = user.Longitude
                alluser_lat = user.Latitude
                distance = calculateDistance(current_user_long, current_user_lat, alluser_long, alluser_lat)
                if distance > distparam:
                    newQueryset.push(user)
            return newQueryset
        return queryset
class UserFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields =['gender', 'last_name', 'first_name' ]
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filterset_class = UserFilter
    filter_backends = CustomFilter
```

Models.py

```
class User(AbstractUser):
   username = None
   email = models.EmailField(
       max_length=100, verbose_name='email', unique=True)
   gender = models.CharField(
       max_length = 20,
       choices = GENDER_CHOICES,
       default = 'М'
       )  
   avatar= ProcessedImageField(upload_to='avatars',
                                          processors=[ResizeToFill(400, 400), Watermark()],
                                          format='JPEG',
                                          options={'quality': 72})    
   likes = models.ManyToManyField('User', blank=True, related_name="like")
   latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)
   longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=22, decimal_places=16, blank=True, null=True)
   USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
   REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
   objects = UserManager()
```

Comment: Consider using [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/#) you can use it to do distance queries https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/gis/db-api/#distance-queries

Comment: why using this library if i already implemented the function that calcuates the distance ?

Comment: Because you have to fetch, loop over and run your function against every user in the DB which will be very inefficient. Doing the filter on the DB will be faster and more efficient as you won't have to transfer the data from the entire user table

Answer (score 0):

I think the error appearing here is not related to distance calculation/filtering, it might be incorrect settings
Please make sure that DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS is a valid tuple or a list

Comment: everything is okay with the settings

Comment: Can you post your REST_FRAMEWORK settings key

Comment: REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   
     'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': [
         'django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'
         ],
     'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
         'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    
}